# ssh intermittently stalling on "debug1: identity file /Users/jason/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1"

Tags: performance, ssh

I sometimes need to connect to my server over a slow (1.5Mbps up 500Kbps down) connection. It is my mobile phone connection. When I do this, ssh will intermittently stall at

```
jason:>ssh -vvv jason@www.randalds.com.au
OpenSSH_5.6p1, OpenSSL 0.9.8y 5 Feb 2013
debug1: Reading configuration data /Users/jason/.ssh/config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug1: Reading configuration data /etc/ssh_config
debug1: Applying options for *
debug2: ssh_connect: needpriv 0
debug1: Connecting to www.randalds.com.au [119.9.40.12] port 22.
debug1: Connection established.
debug3: Not a RSA1 key file /Users/jason/.ssh/id_rsa.
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----BEGIN'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug3: key_read: missing whitespace
debug2: key_type_from_name: unknown key type '-----END'
debug3: key_read: missing keytype
debug1: identity file /Users/jason/.ssh/id_rsa type 1
debug1: identity file /Users/jason/.ssh/id_rsa-cert type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jason/.ssh/id_dsa type -1
debug1: identity file /Users/jason/.ssh/id_dsa-cert type -1
```

I don't really want to use server keys, as I use make to deploy my code, and I like having to enter a password before the code is uploaded in case I change my mind. I found no way of turning off ssh authenticating by key first though, so I thought perhaps generating an RSA key server side and local side would make a difference. It didn't.

This is recent, I have always been able to log on with ssh on slow connections, and back 10 years ago, I remember doing so successfully with my 56K modem. What I would really like is adequate encryption AND the ability to connect when I am off site or away from the office. I have tried using "ssh -xC", and various settings of

```
GSSAPIAuthentication yes
GSSAPIDelegateCredentials no
```

But to no avail. Telnet used to be fast as hell on a 56K modem. Is there a way to get ssh as fast as this?

Answer (score 1):

Try turning off DNS lookups on the server side.  The corresponding setting is "UseDNS=no" in sshd_config. You can find the configuration under /etc/ssh/sshd_config on most Linux distros.

Comment: I have actually tried this. It made no difference though.